# Changing the height of a dropdown list in asp

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, drop-down-menu

This is what I am trying to do:
[This is where I start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwDas.png)

When I now click on the dropdown it opens the list like usual.

[This is what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Xlyf.png)

The red area is what I want the dropdown-height to be.
I know that I can't change it with simple asp commands or css.
I thought i could do it with javascript but it never really worked out. 
Is this even possible? 
If it's not possible, can you tell me why?

Any advice is appreciated. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You need to provide us actual code from your project better a jsFiddle or codepen otherwise we won't be able to help you.

Comment: Well ok I took out almost everything we don't need in this dilemma.So you won't be able to run it: https://jsfiddle.net/om5bw3pp/11/

Comment: Your code not reproduce your problem so i'm unable to help you.

Comment: Ofc it does. ^^
I want to ADD a feature I don't have in my code, what did you expect you'd see in my code?
I simply wanted to know if there is the possibility to increase the height of a dropdown list. That't it.